# Extends class and change properties

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a `Button` class with a `text` property :

```
export default class Button extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.text = 'Text'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>
                {this.text}
            </Text>
        )
    }
}
```

And another `ButtonSuccess` class extended `Button` :

```
export default class ButtonSuccess extends Button {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.text= 'Hello'
    }
}
```

**It works well :)**

And now, I wish to eventually redefine the text with the tag `text` :

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ButtonSuccess text="Se connecter" />
        )
    }
}
```

**How to do ?**
I can add this in the constructor of the `Button` class but I think it too heavy (especially if I have several properties) :

```
if (undefined !== this.props.text) {
    this.text = this.props.text
}
```

Comment: I'm not really big on ReactNative, but in simple ReactJS, just try as ```this.props.text="Hello"``` in constructor

Comment: why use class for button component, rather than use a simple function ??????? @Gaylord.P

Comment: Oh yeah exactly XD, `const Button = ({buttonText}) => { return(); } export default Button;` This is more easier than using a class based component.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no need to save it as an instance variable or even to the state if you don't plan on changing it inside the component. You can just pass it as a prop and access it directly in render, while also provide a default value if needed:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ButtonSuccess text={this.props.text || 'Hello'} />
        )
    }
}
```

Alternative you can provide default value via `defaultProps`:

```
Login.defaultProps = {
  text: 'Hello'
}
```

Comment: Is it a good thing to create a variable like `this.text` instead of using in a state? Just for knowledge

Comment: Thank you but I want to preserve the default texts `Button` and `ButtonSuccess` :)

Comment: Default text, then use that default props thingy in PropTypes

Comment: XD @Clarity check my comment on the question, Functional component XD.

Comment: But wait, is it possible to use defaultProps with functional components? Again just for knowledge.

Comment: @yes, it is or you can just define those directly in function declaration: `const Button = ({text='Hello'}) => //...`

Comment: Alright, edit edit XD, this will finally answer the whole question in the layman terms.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke It can be either functional or class component in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* <ButtonSuccess /> */}
        <ButtonSuccess text='hello2' />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const Button = ({text}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        {text}
    </div>
  )
}

const ButtonSuccess = ({button_success_text}) => {
    return(
      <>
      {/* <Button /> */}
      <Button text={button_success_text} />
      </>
    )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  text: 'text'
}

ButtonSuccess.defaultProps = {
  button_success_text: 'button_success'
}

export default App;
```